# how to animated swiper.js slider like modern slider

Tags: javascript, carousel, swiper.js

This slider has 3 slides per view and also has a full-width background image. Whenever the slider changes, the background image will change according to the slider index. I tried animating it like the site https://stinna-it.nl/alle-projecten. Not only did I try to animate it, I tried to create exactly this slider using Swiper.js. For the animation, I used GSAP but I can only use autoAlpha for now; if I try to use other things like `scale(0)` to `scale(1)`, it gets messed up.

```js
  const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".prjctbg");

  var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    spaceBetween: 1,
    slidesPerView: 2.5,
    centeredSlides: true,
    roundLengths: true,
    loop: true,
    loopAdditionalSlides: 30,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    on: {
      slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
        // Get the current slide index
        var slideIndex = this.realIndex;
         // console.log(slideIndex);
        imgs.forEach((img) => {
          const index = img.getAttribute("data-index");
          if (index == slideIndex) {
            img.classList.add("activeBG");
          } else {
            img.classList.remove("activeBG");
          }
        });
        gsap.fromTo(
          ".activeBG",
          1,
          {
            autoAlpha: 0,
            scale: 1.2,
          },
          {
            autoAlpha: 1,
            scale: 1,
          }
        );
      },
    },
    breakpoints: {
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
      },
    },
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,200&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.projectSlider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.projectSlider .swiper-pagination-fraction,
.projectSlider .swiper-pagination-custom,
.projectSlider .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: 26px;
}
.projectSlider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-prev {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.projectSlider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.projectSlider .swiper-button-prev,
.projectSlider .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("../images/icons/prev.svg");
  left: inherit;
  right: 100px;
}
.projectSlider .swiper-button-next,
.projectSlider .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("../images/icons/next.svg");
  right: 35px;
  left: auto;
}
.projectSlider .swiper-button-prev,
.projectSlider .swiper-button-next {
  top: 94%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
.projectSlider .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.projectSlider .prjctbg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
.projectSlider .prjctbg.activeBG {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
}

.swiper-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  text-align: center;
}
.swiper-slide p {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.swiper-slide p span {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
  display: block;
}
.swiper-slide h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3.8em;
  line-height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  font-weight: 600;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active p {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active p span {
  transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  display: block;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active h1 {
  transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
   <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.2/css/swiper.css"
/>
   <!-- slider section section -->
        <div class="projectSlider">
          <img
            src="https://i.im.ge/2022/12/16/dHOzYJ.windows-FV6Pma5U-98-unsplash.jpg"
            data-index="0"
            alt=""
            class="prjctbg"
          />
          <img
            src="https://i.im.ge/2022/12/16/dH2dSz.jenny-ueberberg-BaSeK7rwc1A-unsplash.jpg"
            data-index="1"
            alt=""
            class="prjctbg"
          />
          <img
            src="https://i.im.ge/2022/12/16/dHOzYJ.windows-FV6Pma5U-98-unsplash.jpg"
            data-index="2"
            alt=""
            class="prjctbg"
          />
          <img
            src="https://i.im.ge/2022/12/16/dH2dSz.jenny-ueberberg-BaSeK7rwc1A-unsplash.jpg"
            data-index="3"
            alt=""
            class="prjctbg"
          />
          <img
            src="https://i.im.ge/2022/12/16/dHOzYJ.windows-FV6Pma5U-98-unsplash.jpg"
            data-index="4"
            alt=""
            class="prjctbg"
          />
          <img
             src="https://i.im.ge/2022/12/16/dH2dSz.jenny-ueberberg-BaSeK7rwc1A-unsplash.jpg"
            data-index="5"
            alt=""
            class="prjctbg"
          />
          <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide-container">
                  <a href="#" class="details">
                    <h1 class="elmt">
                      Audiovisual <br />
                      Design
                    </h1>
                    <p class="elmt">
                      <span> Video Installation</span>
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide-container">
                  <a href="#" class="details">
                    <h1 class="elmt">
                      Exhibition <br />
                      Design
                    </h1>
                    <p class="elmt">
                      <span> Multimedia Exhibition</span>
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide-container">
                  <a href="#" class="details">
                    <h1 class="elmt">
                      Texts and <br />
                      Images
                    </h1>
                    <p class="elmt">
                      <span> website + Print Magazine </span>
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide-container">
                  <a href="#" class="details">
                    <h1 class="elmt">
                      Material and <br />
                      Light
                    </h1>
                    <p class="elmt">
                      <span> Short Video</span>
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide-container">
                  <a href="./projectDetails.html" class="details">
                    <h1 class="elmt">
                      Dimension <br />
                      Design
                    </h1>
                    <p class="elmt">
                      <span> Rendered Image </span>
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide-container">
                  <a href="./projectDetails.html" class="details">
                    <h1 class="elmt">
                      App <br />
                      Design
                    </h1>
                    <p class="elmt">
                      <span> Sustainability App</span>
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
```